# CE and FCC compliance

Tags: fcc, ce, compliance

I was browsing and found some very informative answers on this site. They didn't specifically answer my question, so I decided to Register and ask ...

We are importing digital cameras from Europe. These cameras have a CE certification (i.e., they have been tested and found to comply with the CE requirements (test protocols available). For use in the US they need of course FCC compliance, which is a voluntary test for unintentional emitters.

1) To my knowledge, the CE requirements are more expansive than the FCC requirements, and also more stringent. Does CE compliance then automatically imply FCC compliance? CE also Comes in different classes (A-E, I think). Does a specific class then perhaps imply FCC compliance?

2) Some of the tests are made with specific configurations (shielded cables, etc). Is this then part of the configuration, i.e., do the products have to be sold with the parts used for the tests (for example with the shielded cable), or can the products be sold without the parts , perhaps with a note that in order to reach FCC compliance certain parts are necessary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> CE also Comes in different classes (A-E, I think)

No it doesn't but, some of the sub-testing/approvals (as specified by applicable EU directives) such as the EMC directive, have certain sub-classes i.e. part A and B emissions etc..

Blow is what [this](http://www.pseinc.com/faq.htm) site says about FCC part 15 (Electromagnetic interference): -

> What about the new FCC Part 15 Self Declaration Procedures?
>
> Under the new procedures for DoC/Self Declaration there is no longer a
>   need to submit/certify computing devices and peripherals with the FCC.
>
> The manufacture simply has the testing performed at a A2LA approved
>   OATS, applies the new FCC label to there product, and issues a
>   Declaration of Conformity to be shipped with the product. The real
>   benefit is that there is longer a submittal to the FCC, so a product
>   can hit the market as soon as it is shown to be in compliance, saving
>   several weeks in the overall process.

I'm in the UK and I read this as meaning you just can't rely on any CE technical documents for short-cutting the procedure in the US especially for EMI. Furthermore, the same link clarifies this a bit about testing: -

> Differences in emissions limits?
>
> I have heard that the emissions requirements for Europe, Japan, the US
>   and several other countries are all very similar.  Is it possible to
>   perform one test that covers several markets for emissions?
>
> Depending on the type of product that you manufacture, it may be
>   possible to perform one emissions test, generally based on the CISPR
>   22 limits, and only perform deviations for the other markets.
>
> However, it is important to confirm that your test lab is qualified
>   and accredited to perform testing for these different markets. For
>   example, the VCCI (Japan) requires that the testing laboratory be a
>   member, and if you are going to self declare a computing device to
>   meet FCC Part 15 requirements, the lab must be A2LA accredited. PSE
>   holds both of these accreditations.
>
> Keep in mind that whether you are trying to meet EMC or safety
>   standards, it is always important to define all intended markets
>   before testing begins. PSE always strives to meet our client's needs
>   in the most cost effective and time efficient course possible. By
>   having a clear understanding of which markets you are seeking, we will
>   be in a better position to satisfy your needs.

The key point is that if the UK or overseas (outside the US) lab has A2LA accreditation then this makes it an easier exercise.

Comment: Good answer, but doesn't address the second question re cables.